# Insert Image & Text in a Spread Sheet Cell

Tags: image, google-sheets, excel-formula

Hi guys and a happy Sunday morning to you all!

I hope you guys are having a great start to this Sunday!!!

I have been playing with this for the past 2 hours and can not figure out how to combine text and an image in the same cell.

In Google Spreadsheets it is possible to show an image in a cell using this formula
=Image("http://www.example.com/path/to/image.ext")

Now I have a cell with a image in it.

After this image is populated in the cell, I want to add text in the beginning of the image.

I am using the formula below.

=IMAGE("http://www.example.com/path/to/image.ext")&"Test Test"

but when I add the text after the ampersand in the formula, my image disappears and the cell only populates the text (Test Test).

Can you please help me out ?

Thank you all for your on going help!!

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible in a single cell. One work-around is to put the caption (i.e. text) is a cell directly above or below the cell containing the image and formatting borders to remove the display of any cell separation.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by surrounding the image with quotes. e.g. =""&" Test".

Comment: Add more description, information, reference, etc. and from when its started supporting.